# jQuery: how to trigger anchor link's click event

Tags: jquery

I have a anchor link like

```
<a id="myanchor" href="http://google.com" target="_blank">Google</a>
```

How to open href target in a new tab programatically?

Comment: using `_blank` will automatically open in new tab , where is the problem dude??

Comment: links, by default standard action, open your `href` on a click. why do you want to do this via Javascript?

Comment: i need to trigger this click prgramatically on page load...

Comment: Anyone knows why both 
$('#myanchor').click();
// OR
$('#myanchor').trigger('click'); doesn't automatically click the link

Comment: @Ram because probably the element `#myanchor` hasn't had a click event handler bound to it, so there is nothing to call.

Answer (score 120, accepted):

Try the following:

`$("#myanchor")[0].click()`

As simple as that.

Comment: thats right! reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.click

Comment: it kindof works, but in firefox and chrome, if the link is used to download something (this was not the op question but still) with target="_blank", the browser blocks the popup (depending on its configuration), which is not EXACTLY the same as if a human user was clicking with it with the mouse (no block).

Comment: This works by calling the native (non-jQuery) click function of the first element (0-th) in the set of #myanchor jQuery objects.

Answer (score 26):

There's a difference in invoking the `click` event (does not do the redirect), and navigating to the `href` location.

Navigate:

```
 window.location = $('#myanchor').attr('href');
```

Open in new tab or window:

```
 window.open($('#myanchor').attr('href'));
```

invoke click event (call the javascript):

```
 $('#myanchor').click();
```

Comment: Navigate is fine but i need to open href in a new tab. when i user window.location it is opening in the same tab.

Comment: @Venkat: try the `window.open` in the next example

Comment: People need to read properly. If you are trying to call `$(...).click();` on an element that hasn't had the click event handler bound, triggering the jQuery `click()` will do nothing. If you are trying to automatically click an anchor tag give it an `id` like `myanchor` and use the third example `$('#myanchor').click();`.

Comment: window.location = $('#myanchor').attr('href') worked perfectly for an anchor that I had within the same page.  I had <a name="somename"></a> at the top of the page, <a id="myanchor" href="somename"></a> elsewhere, then used your trick to cause the page to move to the anchor point.

Answer (score 20):

Even though this post is caput, I think it's an excellent demonstration of some walls that one can run into with jQuery, i.e. thinking `click()` actually clicks on an element, rather than just sending a click event bubbling up through the DOM. Let's say you *actually need* to simulate a click event (i.e. for testing purposes, etc.) If that's the case, provided that you're using a modern browser you can just use `HTMLElement.prototype.click` (see [here for method details as well as a link to the W3 spec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.click)). This should work on almost all browsers, especially if you're dealing with links, and you can fall back to `window.open` pretty easily if you need to:

```
var clickLink = function(linkEl) {
  if (HTMLElement.prototype.click) {
    // You'll want to create a new element so you don't alter the page element's
    // attributes, unless of course the target attr is already _blank
    // or you don't need to alter anything
    var linkElCopy = $.extend(true, Object.create(linkEl), linkEl);
    $(linkElCopy).attr('target', '_blank');
    linkElCopy.click();
  } else {
    // As Daniel Doezema had said
    window.open($(linkEl).attr('href'));
  }
};
```

Comment: Hi there, 

How do you call this?  

<pre><code>var linkEl = 'http://www.google.com';
clickLink();</code></pre>

Thanks,

dennis

Comment: @Dennis `clickLink($('#myanchor'));`  or try  `clickLink($('#myanchor')[0]);`

Answer (score 2):

```
 window.open($('#myanchor').attr('href'));

               $('#myanchor')[0].click();
```

Comment: `$('#myanchor')[0].click` is undefined, because subscripting removes the jQuery decorator. You have to use either `$($('#myanchor')[0]).click();` or `$('#myanchor').first().click();`.

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me:

```
     window.location = $('#myanchor').attr('href');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(":button").click(function () {                
                $("#anchor_google")[0].click();
            });
```

1. First, find the button by type(using ":") if id is not given.
2. Second,find the anchor tag by id or in some other tag like div and $("#anchor_google")[0] returns the DOM object.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot open in a new tab programmatically, it's a browser functionality. You can open a link in an external window . Have a look [here](http://web.oddist.org/Javascript/js_design/basic/js06.html)

Comment: then what if user disable popus?

Comment: Please include the contents of the link. The link is no longer valid