# How to Convert A Tab Key Press Into An Enter Key Press For Web Pages?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am create a form in html for submit data. When I shall reach save button by tab press and press tab again then tab will act as a Enter key. That means data will save. How can i do this?

I have use the following code

```
 <form id="form">
<input type="text" />
<input type="text" />
<input type="text" />
<input disabled="disabled" />
<input readonly="readonly" value="readonly" />
<textarea></textarea>

<input type="submit" />
```

```
$(":input").on("keydown", function(event) {
    if (event.which == 9) {
        event.startPropagation();
    }
});
```

Please tell me the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

an alternative to mjalajel 's answer

```
$("input[type='submit']").on("keyup", function(event) {
    if (event.which == 9) {
        $(this).trigger('click');
    }
});
```

this way whatever you have on click event is called

if you want to follow a link, you have to replace

```
$(this).trigger('click');
```

with

```
this.click();
```

this is because jquery click event isn't the same as a "real" click
more info here: [jQuery: how to trigger anchor link's click event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6068266/jquery-how-to-trigger-anchor-links-click-event)

Comment: Thanks. You code is working. I am facing another problem. How can i go a new link using tab. Here is my code http://jsfiddle.net/alamin5433/T93N7/

Comment: edited with a possible way to do that, tough you have to check if this is crossbrowser

Comment: Jarry, Code is not working for safari and firefox 16

Answer (score 1):

I assume this is what you're trying to achieve

```
$("input[type='submit']").on("keyup", function(event) {
    if (event.which == 9) {
        $('#form').submit();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks it works. I have another problem. How can i go the next page using tab. just next button instead of save.  this is the next button code     <div class="next"><a class="next-button" href="#second">Next</a></li></div>

Comment: I have tried Jarry's code. But not working. Please check here http://jsfiddle.net/alamin5433/T93N7/