# jQuery use .on(load) with ajax loaded content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, onload

I have a webpage with AJAX loaded content. If I click on "export" the content reloads and generate an HTML a-Element using PHP:

```
<a style=\"display:none;\" id=\"menue-export-link\" href=\"download/".$this->select->downloadcsv."\"></a>
```

Now I want to start the download automatically, so I wrote the following JavaScript code to start the download on a-Element load:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on('load', '#menue-export-link', function() {
        console.log('click export');
        $('#menue-export-link').click();
        $('#menue-export-link').remove();
    });
});
```

But nothing happens, does somebody have any idea?

Comment: Use [trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all there is no `load` or `onload` event for html anchor elements.
So as @The F said you have to trigger the download in your ajax success callback. Remember to find and trigger it after you have appended the html in your DOM. For more on jQuery ajax http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

And now comes triggering the download part. Triggering the click event which causes the navigation is a bit trickier. The following question answers that very well [jQuery: how to trigger anchor link's click event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6068266/jquery-how-to-trigger-anchor-links-click-event) and 
[How can I simulate an anchor click via jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/773639/how-can-i-simulate-an-anchor-click-via-jquery)

Comment: Thanks a lot :-)
This was the next problem. I resolved it with the specification of the element Index: `$('#menue-export-link')[0].click(); `

Comment: I actually faced the same problem triggering anchor element's click event :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on("click", "#menue-export-link", function() {
  console.log("click export");
});
```

Comment: I think she/he wants to avoid a click, but wants to trigger the download once the link has actually been loaded.

Comment: Anyway, dynamically created elements needs trigger as above

Answer (score 0):

Your js is triggered when your main page is loaded and `#menue-export-link` probably does not exist to that time. If using `$.ajax` to load that link, place your javascript inside the [success](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) callback to make sure that your link exists or is being loaded before triggering your code.

Comment: Thanks, it was actually to easy :D

Comment: I resolved it like this:

`
if($('#menue-export-link').length) {
     console.log('click export');
     $('#menue-export-link').click(); 
    }
`

Comment: Glad it works. However, next time try to solve it using the tools given by jQuery. We could help you more if you'd share your actual ajax call. Ashraf shared some nice recources as well.