# Trigger on document load not working

Tags: jquery

Basically i want to call click event as soon as the document is loaded.   Below is the sample code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
            $("a").trigger("click");
     });

    </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <a href="http://google.com/">Link</a>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: And now? What is your question? Does it work as expected or not? What do you expect to happen?

Comment: seems duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2060019/how-to-trigger-click-on-page-load

Comment: no its not..its lil different..thanks anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to navigate using href of anchor and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6068266/jquery-how-to-trigger-anchor-links-click-event) is why:

```
window.location =  $("a").attr('href');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery( "a" ).on( "click", function() {

 window.open('http://www.google.com');
});
jQuery( "a" ).trigger( "click" );
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="#">Link</a>
</body>
</html>
```