# Javascript - click a link that begins with something

Tags: javascript

I have a link like this:

```
<a href="mypage.php?x=123456"></a>
```

I need a javascript code to click this link on page load, but since the code generated after "?" is random , i need the script clicking the url starting with "mypage.php" .

How do i achieve this?
Thank you in advance

Comment: You have omitted your code? Please ensure your using the right markdown

Comment: a moderator edited my post , now it's ok

Comment: Why would you need a javascript that clicks a link?

Comment: it's for testing purpose, i could do it in php but i want to know the javascript way

Comment: No idea why your question is being downvoted. Basically you'll have to gather all href's and parse the strings to find out which ones begin with mypage.php, then trigger a click on those. This is really basic string manipulation.

Comment: `window.location = $("a").attr("href");`

Comment: @BradEvans can you post a code? i know nothing about javascript

Comment: @KunalKhivensara considering i have multiple links on the same page, will this work?

Comment: @Tony33 How your are deciding which link to click on there can be multiple links like eg: `<a href="mypage.php?123434"></a><a href="mypage.php?123434"></a><a href="mypage.php?123470"></a>`

Comment: @KunalKhivensara consider i have multiple links on the same page, but only one is mypage.php , of course. So i need the script click and open mypage.php

Comment: @Tony33 You have answers now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the "starts with" selector `^=`

```
$( "a[href^='mypage.php']" ).on( "click", function(){
    //do smething
} );
```

## edit

Oh, i got your point. This is what you need.

```
$( "a[href^='mypage.php']" ).trigger( "click" );
```

## edit2

i've figured out that you may have no jQuery in page. So, here is a fiddle with the propper solution: https://jsfiddle.net/shhzncw1/1/

And here is your script:

```
(function(){
    var el = document.querySelector('a[href^="mypage.php"]');
    var evt;
    if (document.createEvent) {
        evt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
        evt.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
    }
    (evt) ? el.dispatchEvent(evt) : (el.click && el.click());
})();
```

## edit 3

But if your intent is just to go to the page, you could just do a redirect. Think about it. (:

```
(function(){
    var el = document.querySelector('a[href^="mypage.php"]');
    var href = el.href;
    window.location.href = href;
})();
```

Comment: This. But: `$("a[href^='mypage.php']").trigger("click");`

Comment: yes, thanks, after i posted, i figured out his need. (:

Comment: @FilipeMerker i tried this but the page mypage.php doesn't open

Comment: @FilipeMerker ehm..no? i've put it in <script></script> tags

Answer (score 0):

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        window.location = $('#myanchor').attr('href');
    });
```

HTML

```
<a href="mypage.php?123456" id="myanchor"></a>
```

Check this post --> [jQuery: how to trigger anchor link's click event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6068266/jquery-how-to-trigger-anchor-links-click-event)

Comment: and considering i don't have id property? but href only

Answer (score 0):

You can try these :-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        window.location = $("a[href^='mypage.php']").attr('href');
});
```