# jQuery dynamic anchor doesn't work

Tags: jquery

My post method receives an object with the path to a dynamic created pdf, and I want to open the pdf. But some browser shows `blocked popup` in functions like `window.open()`. Then I'm trying to create an anchor and trigger a click on it, but doesn't seems to work:

```
$http.post('/Export/Create', params).success(function (o) {
    load.fadeOut(function () {
        if (o.Path.match(/\.pdf$/)) {
            console.log('returned PDF');
            var a = $('<a></a>').appendTo('body');
            a.attr({ 'href': o.Path, 'target': '_blank' });
            a.trigger('click');
        }
        // else ...
    });
}).error(function (x) { console.log(x); });
```

I am receiving the `returned PDF` message, so the problem is with the dynamic anchor.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6068266/jquery-how-to-trigger-anchor-links-click-event#answer-12166799 Also Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/773639/how-can-i-simulate-an-anchor-click-via-jquery

Comment: you can try `a.click()`

Comment: @MateiMihai. Still doesn't work :(

Comment: @Stryner. The first answer of the first question worked for me, while still shows `blocked popup` on browser :(

Answer (score 2):

When adding dynamic content after the dom has loaded, the event handlers won't exist for the added elements, so you have to use something like

```
$(document).on("click", "a.anchor_class", function () {
    //click code here
}
```

The 'a' in the second parameter is the element type followed by a class name to hook the listener into e.g. "button.classname".

Additionally, the above `.on("click")` function can exist on the page before your dynamic content is loaded. It will register the clicks just fine after you add the `<a>` in later (as long as you add the matching class name to the `<a>`).

Comment: That's not the case.. I am trying to simple trigger the default action of anchor tag.

Comment: I see, but it still won't trigger because there is no event listener waiting for the trigger call. So you have to do it using the way I posted and call something like $(this).trigger(); in the method.