# Simulate click on Bouton href javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, filemaker

How can i simulate a click on the bouton "edit" by using jquery ?

```
<ul class=​"sa-address-list">​
 <li class=​"sa-address-row util-clearfix">​
  <div class=​"sa-address-wrapper " data-id=​"5445664">​
   <div class=​"sa-address-item    selected" data-id=​"5445664">​
   <input type=​"radio" checked=​"checked" name=​"addressId" class=​"select-radio-input" value=​“5445664”>​
   <div class=​" si-username">​namename​</div>​
   <ul class=​"si-bg sa-location">​…​</ul>​
   <div class=​"si-bg sa-mobile-number">​phone​</div>​
   <p class=​"si-operation">​…​</p>​
     <a class=​"si-edit" href=​"javascript:​;​">​Edit​</a>
    ​</p>​
  <i class=​“shop here”>​Ship to this address​</i>​
```

Comment: when do you want to simulate it?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6068266/jquery-how-to-trigger-anchor-links-click-event

Comment: in filemaker with an script instead of click to "edit" i click to the script who run javascript or jquery

Answer (score 0):

`$('.si-edit').trigger('click');`
http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

or

`$('.si-edit').click();`
http://api.jquery.com/click/

Comment: Try this, the inline javascript didn't seem to work: https://jsfiddle.net/80cj32fn/11/

Comment: i have to use it in filemaker with plugin who run javascript, i made work this for select : MBS( "WebView.RunJavaScript"; "WV"; "$('span:contains(" & field of what i want select&")').trigger('click');" ) but simulate the click on edit i could't find

Comment: i find this in source maybe that could help you :  n.on("click", ".sa-address-wrapper .si-edit", function(e) {
                var t = i(this);
                if (t.closest(".sa-address-item").length) {
                    return 
                }
                t.closest(".sa-address-wrapper").find(".sa-address-item .si-edit").trigger("click")
            });