# Why do jQuery .click() / .trigger() methods not follow hyperlinks yet pure JS does?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Thanks to a question asked earlier, I've noticed that the jQuery `.trigger()` (and obviously its shorthand `.click()`) don't fully work on hyperlinks. The event gets triggered perfectly fine, it's just as if it adds `preventDefault()` to it?

I was wondering why this is happening? Not looking for a solution because I know it would be easy to just grab the href attribute value and use JS to navigate towards the url instead.

Proof of concept:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Method 1
  var btn1 = document.getElementById('btn1');
  var link1 = document.getElementById('link1');

  btn1.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    fireEvent(document.getElementById('link1'), 'click');
  });

  link1.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    console.log('Click on link1 triggered.');
  });

  function fireEvent(node, eventName) {
    var doc;
    if (node.ownerDocument) {
      doc = node.ownerDocument;
    } else if (node.nodeType == 9){
      doc = node;
    } else {
      throw new Error("Invalid node passed to fireEvent: " + node.id);
    }

    if (node.dispatchEvent) {
      var eventClass = "";

      switch (eventName) {
        case "click":
        case "mousedown":
        case "mouseup":
          eventClass = "MouseEvents";
          break;

        case "focus":
        case "change":
        case "blur":
        case "select":
          eventClass = "HTMLEvents";
          break;

        default:
          throw "fireEvent: Couldn't find an event class for event '" + eventName + "'.";
      }
      var event = doc.createEvent(eventClass);
      event.initEvent(eventName, true, true);

      event.synthetic = true;
      node.dispatchEvent(event, true);
    } else  if (node.fireEvent) {
      var event = doc.createEventObject();
      event.synthetic = true;
      node.fireEvent("on" + eventName, event);
    }
  }

  // Method 2
  $(document).on('click', '#btn2', function(e){
    $('#link2').trigger('click');
  });

  $(document).on('click', '#link2', function(e){
    console.log('Click on link2 triggered.');
  });

  // Method 3
  $('#btn3').click(function(e){
    $('#link3').click();
  });

  $('#link3').click(function(e){
    console.log('Click on link3 triggered.');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4>jQuery click / trigger events not following hyperlinks</h4><br/>
Method 1: Using pure JS<br/>
<button id="btn1">Button 1</button>
<a id="link1" href="https://google.com">Google</a><br/><br/>
Method 2: Using jQuery .on and .trigger methods<br/>
<button id="btn2">Button 2</button>
<a id="link2" href="https://google.com">Google</a><br/><br/>
Method 3: Using jQuery .click method<br/>
<button id="btn3">Button 3</button>
<a id="link3" href="https://google.com">Google</a>
```

A jsFiddle in case you want to play around with it yourself: https://jsfiddle.net/ap8whL9u/

Comment: This is actually expected. According to the [documentation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/triggering-event-handlers/): *"The `.trigger()` function cannot be used to mimic native browser events, such as clicking on a file input box or an anchor tag. This is because, there is no event handler attached using jQuery's event system that corresponds to these events."*. You may also want to read [this Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6068266/5768908).

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Thank you. I will actually close this question as a duplicate of that Q/A as it clearly answers my question. Much appreciated!